# Is there anything I should configure after updating to Ubuntu 10.4?

Tags: upgrade, ubuntu-10.04

I just finished updating to 10.04, and after rebooting...it looks pretty much the same. I don't see any difference in the desktop, windows, applications, etc.

Are there any new settings I should explore?  Any functionality I'm missing because I updated an existing account, vs re-creating it?

Comment: if you want to explore, try creating a new user and checking out the default desktop from that perspective.  your account's old settings are hiding some of that from you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are there any new settings I should
>   explore? Any functionality I'm missing
>   because I updated an existing account,
>   vs re-creating it?

You can always create a new "test user" on you pc, 
and then login as this "test user". Then you will get a the new look and feel and you can use this user to play with new settings without breaking your "real" account.

/Have fun

Answer (score 0):

If you update an existing ubuntu installation, your apps, looks etc. will remain the same. However all the key features are added. I guess you should look for the difference between an upgrade and a fresh install online to get a clear picture of what changes and what doesn't.